# Concurrent Programming act on each element in array

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a question whch related to parallel programming. If I have a program that acts on each and every elemnt of an array why might it not be advantagous to use all the available processors?

I was thinking maybe because of the significant overhead of setting up and managing multiple threads or if the array size didnt warrant a concurrent solution. Can anyone think of anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Some processors may already be busy doing important things, or you may want to leave spare capacity just in case they need to respond quickly to new workloads. For example, in a desktop system with 8 processors, you may want to leave 1 free to keep the UI responsive, while you fork out 7 "batch-processing" threads on the others. In a non-UI system, you may still want to keep one or more cores listening to OS interrupts or doing network IO.

A particularly frustrating example would be starting a parallel computation on all your cores, finding that you should have tweaked a parameter before launching it, and not being able to interrupt the computation because there is no spare computing power left to allow the UI to respond to your 'cancel' button.

Answer (score 0):

I would have made that array a static variable and according to its size, I would have divided the task and assigned multiple treads to carry the work for each set of elements in the array.

For example, If I have 100 elements in the array. I would have divided it and made sets of 10.
and with 10 different threads I would have carried out my work.

Correct me if I am not getting you.

**EDITED:-**
The OS already does precisely that for you. It doesn't guarantee that each thread will stay on the same core forever (and in nearly all cases, there's no need for that either), but it does try to keep as many cores busy as possible. Which means giving all available threads their own core as much as possible.
Note:- Direct correlation between program threads and OS threads is not guaranteed, at least according to this for .net : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx

Hope this make some sense.

Comment: I know what would be the best way to do it. But the lecturer asked the question "If I have a program that acts on each and every elemnt of an array why might it not be advantagous to use all the available processors?" and I can't think of an answer

Comment: @user3036237 Check my edited answer and if it make sense then you can vote for it.